# Mathematica is not able to plot this DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to integrate function `f(k,t,p)` and plot real part of it (heat map).But some how Mathematica always always shown "running..". Can you help me or suggest some workaround. Thanks in advance

```
f = Exp[I 2 t] Exp[I ( k Cos[t - p])]
g = Re[Integrate[f, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
DensityPlot[g, {k, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Here `I = Root(-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your definition functions and use numerical integration

```
f[k_, t_, p_] := Exp[I 2 t] Exp[I (k Cos[t - p])]
g[k_, p_] := Re[NIntegrate[f[k, t, p], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
DensityPlot[g[k, p], {k, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Hubble07, I am so thankful for your reply. You have given me new hope. But when I copy paste your code, it says $Failed, without even waiting. Please advice.

Comment: Close mma & open in new session it should work.